# Eclipse is not showing any search results for dependencies

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven-plugin

I'm trying to download Spring dependencies for pom.xml file in Maven Project using eclipse IDE. When I goto>> pom.xml file>>dependencies>>Select dependency dialogue box
when I enter **springframework** in the search box, no search items are displayed (there is no warning displayed for the same).

Comment: Are [index downloads enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24494049/6505250)? Please add a screenshot of the dialog to your question.

Comment: yes index downloads is enabled

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven not downloading dependencies in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31720328/maven-not-downloading-dependencies-in-eclipse)